# Combine multiple distinct values

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with the following structure:

```
| animal | color |
|--------|-------|
| dog    | black |
| dog    | white |
| cat    | white |
| dog    | black |
| mouse  | grey  |
```

I now want to get the distinct values of each column.

Just doing:

```
SELECT DISTINCT animal, color from tab1
```

Would just omit the 2nd occurrence of `dog - black`:

```
| animal | color |
|--------|-------|
| dog    | black |
| dog    | white |
| cat    | white |
| mouse  | grey  |
```

But what I want is some structure that looks as follows:

```
animal: dog, cat, mouse
color: black, white, grey
```

---

My approach would just be to perform several SELECT queries:

```
 - SELECT DISTINCT animal from tab1
 - SELECT DISTINCT color from tab1
```

And then just combine those results into an array with PHP.

But is there a quicker way, maybe with just one query?

Comment: first up why not clean your data? You have dog,black repeated

Comment: @e4c5 I guess that's what is the concern for OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your second approach is right, but you can do it using `SQL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `animal` from `tab1` UNION SELECT DISTINCT `color` from `tab1`
```

A good thing about UNION is, it already filters your values. So, you can get rid of `DISTINCT` leaving you with:

```
SELECT `animal` from `tab1` UNION SELECT `color` from `tab1`
```

But in this case, you won't be able to differentiate which is from color and which is from animal. You may add a separator `SELECT` and use it to differentiate.

Comment: Thank you, but could you please describe what you mean by `separator SELECT`? I really need to differentiate which groups (animal or color) the values belong to.

Comment: @user1170330 now this would give you all the list of colours and animals combined in a single column right, so to add a separator, add one more `UNION` in the middle, like `UNION SELECT '-----'` so it gives you a differentiation. Let me know if it works. `:D`

Comment: Also, the problem or the advantage in your current situation is, each colour is associated with the particular animal, so it is not possible to split them both unless you use two queries. `:)`

Comment: I would not advice using a seperator-select, but using a second column in your query that states the table name. Something like: SELECT 'animal', `animal` from `tab1` UNION SELECT 'color', `color` from `tab1`

Answer (score 0):

U can group them by the two columns with this sql:

```
SELECT animal, color FROM tab1 GROUP BY animal, color
```

EDIT:

To test my statement i created a mysql table with this SQL:

> CREATE TABLE `animals` (   `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `color` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT
>   CHARSET=utf8;

I populate with this values:

> 1 dog white
>
> 2 dog black
>
> 3 dog white
>
> 4 cat white

When i run this SQL: "SELECT name, color FROM animals GROUP BY name, color"

I got this results:

> cat   white
>
> dog   black
>
> dog   white

If u want to get who has duplicates you can run SQL like this "SELECT name, color, COUNT(ID) as number FROM animals GROUP BY name, color HAVING number > 1" which gives me this result:

> dog   white   2

Hope i helped you.

Comment: Are you sure? Look at Aurios's comment

Comment: Yes i am sure, this will give the same result as distinct by two columns plus u can make something like this SQL: "SELECT animal, color, COUNT(ID) as count_no FROM tab1 GROUP BY animal, color" to count how many occurrence in the table have duplicates. Btw I always check before posting :)